# How to configure/edit objects created in class?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am making a program in python using tkinter with someting like sticky notes that i can move, but now i want to be able to add text to these notes using an Entrybox and a Button but I dont know how to configure the text that was before created in Label that was made using class. I am looking for some solution how to do it if its even possible.
Thats my code:

Edit: Ok so i'll try to make it clear

Here's my whole code:

```
from tkinter import *
import random

class Note:
    

    def __init__(self,master,title,text,color,x_coords,y_coords):

        
        myLabel = Label(master, text=str(title+"\n"+"-"+text),font=("Candara Light",20),height=10,width=13,background=color,anchor=N,wraplength=200)  
        myLabel.place(x=x_coords,y=y_coords)

        
        myLabel.bind("<Button-1>",self.drag_start)
        myLabel.bind("<B1-Motion>",self.drag_motion)

        
    def drag_start(self,event):
        widget = event.widget
        widget.startX = event.x
        widget.startY = event.y

    def drag_motion(self,event):
        widget = event.widget
        x = widget.winfo_x() - widget.startX + event.x
        y = widget.winfo_y() - widget.startY + event.y
        widget.place(x=x,y=y)
    
        
    

def add_text():
    pass

def new_note():
    Note(canvas_frame,add_new_note_title.get(),"",random.choice(note_colors),100,100)


def do_something(event):
    print("You did a thing! " + str(event.x) + "," + str(event.y))

def drag_start(event):
    widget = event.widget
    widget.startX = event.x
    widget.startY = event.y

def drag_motion(event):
    widget = event.widget
    x = widget.winfo_x() - widget.startX + event.x
    y = widget.winfo_y() - widget.startY + event.y
    widget.place(x=x,y=y)

window = Tk()
window.title("To Do")
window.resizable(False,False)

window_width = 900
window_height = 900
screen_width = window.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = window.winfo_screenheight()

x = int((screen_width/2) - (window_width/2))
y = int((screen_height/2) - (window_height/2))

window.geometry(f"{window_width}x{window_height}+{x}+{y}")


blank_label_top = Canvas(window,background="#cbd1cc",width=900,height=70,highlightthickness=0)
blank_label_top.pack(anchor=N)
blank_label_left = Canvas(window,background="#cbd1cc",width=70,height=900,highlightthickness=0)
blank_label_left.pack(anchor=W)

entry = Entry(window,font=("Arial",20),width=25)
entry.place(x=410,y=17)
submit_button = Button(window,text="Add Text",height=2,width=7,font=("Arial"),command=add_text)
submit_button.place(x=800,y=11)

titles = ['Tekst_1','Tekst_2',"Tekst_3"]
title_name = StringVar()
title_name.set("Tekst_1")

title_chooser = OptionMenu(window,title_name,*titles,command=add_text)
title_chooser.place(x=325,y=22)

add_new_note_button = Button(window,text="+",font=("Arial",20),height=1,width=3,background="#cbd1cc",activebackground="#cbd1cc",command=new_note)
add_new_note_button.place(x=230,y=10)

add_new_note_title = Entry(window,width=8,font=("Arial",15))
add_new_note_title.insert(0,"New Title")
add_new_note_title.place(x=120,y=25)

note_colors = ["#d9c389","#53d4c5","#53678a","#d9a9d3","#eef5b3","#a13e2f"]

canvas_frame = Frame(window,highlightthickness=0)
canvas_frame.place(x=70,y=70)

canvas = Canvas(canvas_frame,height=830,width=830,background="#66a9ad",highlightthickness=0)
canvas.pack()

#canvas.create_rectangle(25,25,300,400,fill="pink")




label = Label(canvas,bg="red",width=10,height=5)
#label.place(x=100,y=100)

label.bind("<Button-1>",drag_start)
label.bind("<B1-Motion>",drag_motion)

window.bind("<Button-3>",do_something)

Note_1 = Note(canvas_frame,"Tekst","tekst","#c9a1d1",50,50)
Note_2 = Note(canvas_frame,"Tekst2","tekst2","#3ab5de",290,50)
Note_3 = Note(canvas_frame,"Tekst3","tekst3","#90e8a7",290+240,50)


window.mainloop()
```

ill try to explain this in linked image

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WiIZ8.png

Comment: You need to store `myLabel` in a member variable, like `self.myLabel`.  Then you can do `self.myLabel.config` to change the text.

Comment: But i want to config it outside of class in a different funciton so i dont know how to get access to myLabel

Comment: It's unclear why you don't want to modify it with a `method` and use `self.myLabel`, but if you insist on doing it that way then I would think the simplest way to solve that is to use `global myLabel`

Comment: If you're using it outside the class, you'll have an object of class `Note`.  You just use `object.myLabel`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what the rest of your code looks like, but if you're just trying to accept text input and then display it, something like this might work:

```
    from tkinter import *
def addtxt():
  note = note_inp.get()
  note_disp.insert(0,note)

note_inp = Entry()
note_inp.pack()

ws = Tk()
ws.title('notes')
ws.geometry('200x100')

note_disp = Entry(ws)

note_disp.pack()

btn = Button(
    ws,
    text='add note',
    command = addtxt)
btn.pack()
```

Answer (score 0):

To access and/or modify data that is part of a class from outside the class, it needs to be made an instance variable of the class.

For example, if you want to modify `myLabel` from outside the class you first need to make it an instance variable of the class by using the `self.` prefix.

```
class Note:
    def __init__(self,master,title,text,color,x_coords,y_coords):
        ...
        self.myLabel = Label(master, ...)
        ...
```

Next, you can access the attribute by referencing it from the instance of the class, like so:

```
Note_1 = Note(canvas_frame,"Tekst","tekst","#c9a1d1",50,50)
...
Note_1.myLabel.configure(text="hello, world")
```

Note: this isn't something unique to tkinter. This is a fundamental aspect of python programming. For more information see [Classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#classes) in the official Python documentation.